# Is there a reliable way to extract years from a postgres interval?

Tags: postgresql

In Postgres, if I do the following:

```
select (now() - created_at) from my_table
```

I get results like this:

```
854 days 12:04:50.29658
```

Whereas, if I do:

```
select age(now(), created_at) fro my_table
```

I get results like this:

```
2 years 4 mons 3 days 12:04:50.29658
```

According to `pg_typeof(...)` they are both of type `interval`

But if I try to extract the years:

```
select extract(years from age(now(), created_at)) from my_table
```

I get:

```
2
```

Whereas, with:

```
select extract(years from (now() - created_at)) from my_table
```

I get:

```
0
```

Is there a consistent way to extract the number of years from an interval value (no matter how it was generated)?

Note: I don't have write access to the db, so can't define stored procedures, etc.  Needs to be a select statement.

------ **UPDATE** ------

`justify_interval(...)` was suggested below, but unfortunately it seems to be inaccurate in its calculations.

E.g:

```
select age('2018-01-03'::timestamp, '2016-01-05'::timestamp);
```

gives the correct answer:

```
1 year 11 mons 29 days
```

Whereas:

```
select justify_interval('2018-01-03'::timestamp - '2016-01-05'::timestamp);
```

gives:

```
2 years 9 days
```

I believe this is because it (incorrectly) assumes that all months have 30 days in them

(see `justify_days` 
 here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html)

Comment: I think in all cases you could use to_char() to output the desired presentation

Comment: `justify_interval()` comes to mind

Comment: @verhie I tried to_char(..., 'YYYY') but this doesn't work.  Did you have something else in mind?

Comment: You could divide the number of seconds to get the years: `extract(epoch from '2018-01-03'::timestamp - '2016-01-05'::timestamp) / (365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60)` however that is not as accurate as the years from the interval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `justify_interval` does what you want. Use it in combination with `EXTRACT` to get the years:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(years FROM
               justify_interval(INTERVAL '1 year 900 days 700 hours'));
 date_part 
-----------
         3
(1 row)
```

If 30 days = 1 month isn't accurate enough for you, you'll have to use `EXTRACT` to get the number of days and divide by 365.25.

There is a theoretical limit how exact you can be, because the number of years  in an interval somewhat depends on *between which dates* that interval is.

The two-element `age` function gives a precise result for the number of years between two dates.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz.  This looked promising, but have just tested it, and unfortunately it looks like it isn't accurate.  I'm adding the findings to the end of my answer above.

Comment: I meant "my question above" :)

Comment: I added a suggestion for improvement.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz.  This is certainly an improvement, but will still be a day out sometimes.

Comment: You can't do better, see my extended answer.